# Change password not working php

Tags: php, html

Can you please help me what is wrong with my code? I cannot seem to find the error. My problem is that the new password is not saving in my database. I cannot log in with my new password.

This is my php code.

```
<?php
session_start();
$uid = $_SESSION["uid"];

if($uid)
{
   //user is logged in
   if(isset($_POST["changepwbtn"]))
   {
       // check fields 
       $oldpw = $_POST['old_pw'];
       $newpw = $_POST['new_pw'];
       $renewpw = $_POST['c_npw'];

       //check pw db      
       $sql = "SELECT pazzword FROM customer_info where user_id = '$uid'";
       $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query);   
       $oldpwdb = $row['pazzword'];

       //check pw   
       if($oldpw==$oldpwdb)
       {       
            //check two new pw
            if($newpw==$renewpw)
            {    
                $query_change = mysql_query("UPDATE customer_info SET pazzword = '$newpw' WHERE user_id = '$uid'");
                session_destroy();
                die("Your password has been changed! <a href='index.php'>Return</a>");    
            }
            else
                die("New passwords doesn`t match!");              
       }
       else
           die("Old password doesn`t match");
   }
   echo"  ";    
}
else
    die("You need to log in!");
?>
```

Comment: That's very bad. Lots of errors. Main problem is, your SQL is vulnerable to SQL Injection, while the 2nd major problem is that you're using deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: Firstly, are you sure `$uid` holds any data? Check all the variables that hold the data that you like - if they do then it's all bout the queries. Secondly your first query is executed through `mysqli_` and the second through `mysql_` . As Raptor mentioned above,it's better to use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` .

Comment: Did you encrypt your password? if so following condition doesn't return true value therefore your update query will not executed [ if($oldpw==$oldpwdb) ]

Comment: 1) Check content of `$_SESSION`  (2) Check content of `$_POST` (3) Check if code hits the branches you expect (via print_r/die). This is a matter of debugging. We can't do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the connection object to `mysqli_query`

```
$query_change = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE customer_info SET pazzword = '$newpw' WHERE user_id = '$uid'");
```